# Joomla 3.0: modul.js: $extend is not defined

Tags: migration, joomla3.0

I upgraded from 1.5.x to 3.0.x. During migration the new pages was setup in a separate directory, so the old one could be used without any downtime. After installing all required modules, templates and reorg of some structures I deleted the old page and moved all file from the subdirectory to the root directory. (In addition I change the configuration, so the subdirectory is no longer referenced.) Every thing went well and the user front end seems to be OK. Within the administration pages I have an major issue:

Any page that requires a modal panel (e.g. defining Images for Banners, defining menu items) throws an Javascript error and the page cannot be used:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $extend is not defined modal.js:368
(anonymous function)
```

Do you have any hint how this issue can be solved?

Thanks.

Karsten

Comment: When you are cross-posting, please mention that somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Try re-uploading all files in the directory:

`/media/system/js/`

If the error persists or other error occur, consider uploading the Joomla core files again.

Please not that file by file FTP uploads are sensible to error. It's generally more safe to upload a zip and to unzip everything on the server (not to mention it's faster).

Answer (score 0):

For those that aren't fixed by just re-uploading /media/system/js, this error can crop up for people who do an extremely far upgrade (like 1.5.x to 3.0.x mentioned by the poster) because ["$extend" has been deprecated](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Core/Core#Deprecated-Functions:extend) (and eventually removed) in mootools.

This means that your old extensions may be trying to use code that no longer exists in mootools. If you can find updates for the extension causing the issue, that's probably enough of a fix. If you can't, then it's usually easy enough to fix on your own...

**The short fix for this bug is to change `$extend` to `Object.append`**

Here is some more info about the upgrading mootools in general, which may help with other issues.
https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/wiki/Upgrade-from-1.2-to-1.3-or-1.4